# Web Service method to be invoked at 7 am daily

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, c#-4.0, timer

i have a web service (amsx) in which i want to invoke a method on daily basis, how to do it ? also please no third party dll's

```
public List<myClass> Mymethod(){
     List<myClass> Collect = new List<myClass>();
                if (list.Count == 0)
                {                
                myfunction();  // my function must be invoked every day at 7 to update list
                Collection = list;
                return Collect;
                }

                else
                {                                   
                    Collection = list;                
                    return Collect;
                }
}
```

Comment: Does is a strict requirement that this list must be updated exactly at  7AM? Can it be uppdated later on first MyMethod call?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a look at MSDN article - [Combine Web and Windows Services to Run Your ASP.NET Code at Scheduled Intervals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163821.aspx) and blog post - [Easy Background Tasks in ASP.NET](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/07/easy-background-tasks-in-aspnet/) by Jeff Atwood.

Comment: Fair play, those links are very informative. I always thought something like this would have been very fiddly to do. So +1 from me.

Comment: Agreed, I had to do something like this last year and I used the first of those two articles to solve the problem, so +1 from me too.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use Windows Scheduler to configure your EXE to run at a set time each day? A lot easier then having to come up with some timer-based solution.

With the scheduler, you don't have to bother with any checking of the time. Much easier.

Comment: actually the webservice is inside a web application which is hosted on iis 7

Comment: I would build a console app that can call the web service, and have that console app configured to run via Windows Scheduler. The console app would be on the server, ready to run when set.